# Prevent multiple OPTIONS request for the same domain

Tags: http-headers, cors, httpresponse, response-headers

I am trying to develop a single page application (SPA) that uses as endpoint a domain that is different from the one hosted in the SPA domain (ie: `site.com` and `site-api.com` or `api.site.com`).

Access Control headers are already set up in the back-end, `Max-Age` included, however it does not seem to work.

Here's an example of what happens if I perform the same call multiple times:

[image: google dev tools]

These are the server headers:

- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: `AUTHORIZATION,CONTENT-TYPE`
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: `PATCH`
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: `http://tovertaal.test:3000`
- Access-Control-Max-Age: `600`

Shouldn't `Max-Age` 600 prevent every other `OPTIONS` request within 600 seconds from the first `OPTIONS` request?

The server endpoint is http://tovertaal-api.test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally discovered what was the issue. It seems like **Chrome DevTools**, **when disable cache is active**, also **disables CORS Origin cache**, so it keeps triggering `OPTIONS` request for stuff that should have been cached already.

Make sure to keep caching enabled if you want to test it!